# PHP Convert Textual Month, Day and Year to date data for MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, date

I tried asking this question earlier but I had a prior problem of properly obtaining textual month, day and year date from an input field in an HTML table.

Now that I have obtained this string data, in this case "Aug 25, 2014", I want to convert into date data that will eventually be inserted into a MySQL table.

PHP:

```
$todays_date = strtotime("today");

echo "<form name='timesubmit" . $time_cell_row . "' action='enter_time.php?action=timesubmit" .$time_cell_row . "' method='POST'>";  

echo "<table>"
echo "<th><input name='daycell1' type='text' value='$FormattedCurrDate' readonly/></th>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

/* Code in place to GET action from URL

*/

$date1 = $_POST['daycell1'];
          echo "Date from input field: " . $date1; // displays "Aug 25, 2014
```

How do I take the variable '$date1' and convert it into a date format so that it can be inserted into a MySQL table with a field of type "date"?

Comment: just reformat it again (`date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1))`) before inserting, use date function again, and please don't use `mysql_` functions anymore, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to format your date to be inserted into your table. Then to display it use date function again to display it in a format you want.

```
<?php
$date1 =  $_POST['daycell1']; //I used Aug 25, 2014 in the DEMO.
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date1));
echo $date1; //echoes 2014-08-25 which will be inserted into your table
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/183151)

Comment: @JeffP. You're welcome. I was happy to do it. I know you'll do the same for someone else

Comment: Thanks man, I try to help people when I can!

Comment: For June, 30 2020 00:00:00 , it returns 1970-01-01 which is wrong.Please guide